# Mysql with Node.js: Does it make sense to have node.js save/load stuff to/from the database all the time?

Tags: mysql, performance, node.js

So I have a small game in node.js(only the server of course) which has map data and player accounts stored in a mysql database. Right now I constructed it in a way that minimizes the amount of queries made by loading data from the database and keeping it in javascript objects/arrays or whatever seems appropriate and only writing to the database when needed.

Now I was thinking: Is this really worth it? In many cases it would be alot better(in terms of data would be more save and WAY more up-to-date) to hardly store data in the server and just loading it from the database when needed(respectively writing when it needs to be changed).

My question is: Is it efficient/save/recommendable to have the server read/write from the database often rather than having data from the database in javascript variables in the server?

Additional info:
-The nodejs server and my mysql server are on the same machine and a query usually takes less than 1ms or maybe 3ms for big queries like loading room data.
-I am using a module simply called [mysql](https://npmjs.org/package/mysql).
-If needed I will include extra info, just ask in a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really depends on your Use-Case. Generally speaking, I would not add another layer of caching in node.js but handle that in your db with a bigger cache and optimized queries.

Comment: So in other words I should keep everything in my db and nothing in nodejs itself? Thanks ;)

Comment: Yes, thats what a database is for. You did not write about the size of your data. If not too big, try something like ramfs.